# ActiveRecord Custom Field Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Lets imagine that I have a custom image upload for a particular record and I add two columns into the model.

thumbnail_url
thumbnail_path

Now lets imagine that I have a form with a :file field which is the uploaded file in multipart form. I would need to somehow have the model pickup the file within the given hash and then issue it over to a custom method which performs the upload and saves it as apart of the model.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
def initialize(options = nil)
  if options
    if options[:file]
      self.upload_thumbnail(options[:file])
      options.delete(:file)
    end
    super options
  else
    super
  end
end

def update_attributes(options = nil)
  if options
    if options[:file]
      self.upload_thumbnail(options[:file])
      options.delete(:file)
    end
    super options
  else
    super
  end
end
```

It works, but I am doing some unnecessary overriding here. Is there a simpler way of doing this? Something that would only require overriding perhaps one method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [virtual attributes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes). Just define:

```
def file
  # Read from file or whatever
end

def file=(value)
  # Upload thumbnail and store file
end
```

and `initialize`, `update_attributes` and cousins will pick the methods for you.

That, or save the hassle and use [paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) as Kandada suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using using [paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem? It performs the functions you describe in your question.